# ADFS WAP directs to Apache Tomcat

Tags: tomcat, adfs

I have setup a Active Directory Federation Service and Web Application Proxy servers (each service in one server). I am able to view the IIS Default Web Site when I am outside of the network (not in the same network as the ADFS and WAP servers)
How should the configuration be if I have Apache Tomcat instead of using IIS? I saw SAML, but quite unsure of how it actually works with ADFS WAP and Apache Tomcat.

Comment: Hey xxestter, it sounds like you're trying to setup an apache tomcat server protected by ADFS and WAP. There is alot of configurations required for this, have you seen the post : https://bgstack15.wordpress.com/2016/03/24/adding-adfs-integration-to-apache/ Is this sufficient for your needs?

Comment: @FrankHuMSFT thanks for the reply. I decided to drop ADFS because I can't apply the group policy when user login. Thank you so much for sharing the link.